# Listar todas las bases de datos que contengan una determinada tabla

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, .net

Quiero listar todos las bases de datos de un determinado servidor Sql Server (2008 o superior) que contengan una determinada tabla. He visto varios ejemplos desde cursores, procedimientos almacenados que recorren las bases de datos del servidor hasta el uso de sp_msforeachdb, el cual en varios lugares desaconsejan. ¿Cual seria la mejor forma para hacer esto? 
Pongo como estoy haciéndolo actualmente:

```
    Dim daBBDD As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QUOTENAME(name) Name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0 ORDER BY name", CnxGestion)
    Dim dtBBDD As New DataTable("DDBB")
    daBBDD.Fill(dtBBDD)

    Dim daTable As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dtTable As DataTable

    For Each _bbdd As DataRow In dtBBDD.Rows
        daTable = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLA_BUSCADA'", _bbdd(0)), CnxGestion)
        dtTable = New DataTable(_bbdd(0).ToString)
        daTable.Fill(dtTable)
        If dtTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ''Contiene la tabla
        else
            ''No contiene la tabla
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: y qu problema tienes con tu manera actual ?

Comment: En realidad ninguno pero me gustaría saber si hay alguno mas óptimo.

Comment: Tienes problemas de rendimiento?

Comment: En determinados clientes que tienen una gran cantidad de bases de datos el proceso puede llegar a ser lento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    sys.databases 
WHERE CASE WHEN 
    state_desc = 'ONLINE' THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) 
    + '.[dbo].[TABLA_BUSCADA]', 'U') END IS NOT NULL
```

<sub>Sacado de [esta pregunta de SOeng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141547/display-all-the-names-of-databases-containing-particular-table)</sub>

Comment: Es mas limpia que mi forma. Muchas gracias. Lo único es que solo sería válida si el esquema es dbo pero no creo que sea un problema. Muchas gracias,

Comment: bueno, siempre puedes modificar el `string` para que no sea el esquema `dbo`. Me alegra ser de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Tengo un problema con la consulta. Si en alguna de las bases el usuario que ejecuta la query no tiene permisos, falla.

Comment: @JaimeCapilla mhhh ... miraré a ver que se puede hacer pero los permisos son temas peliagudos.

Comment: @JaimeCapilla no he encontrado nada que pueda funcionar para lo de los privilegios. :/ sorry

Comment: muchas gracias. De momento voy a mantener mi código inicial y con un try catch controlare el error de conexión para determinar los permisos. Igualmente me guardo tu respuesta para otras ocasiones.

Answer (score 0):

Un usuario no puede realizar consultas en BD que no tenga permisos. Lo que podes hacer es ejecutar ese código:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'Domain\User'
query
REVERT
```

La idea es que el usuario que pongas sea uno que tenga permisos  select en todas las bases de datos (o las necesarias) de esta manera aunque sea un usuario sin permiso el que corra el fragmento de código se le mostraran las tablas.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español!, te invito a realizar un recorrido para que comprendas como es su funcionamiento. [CLICK AQUÍ](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). El OP no indica en ningún momento que tenga problemas de permisos al momento de realizar su consulta la base de datos. _Lo que quiere saber cual sería lo óptimo para su procedimiento al momento de listar toda las base de datos que contengan una determinada tabla._ Lo que indicas solo es una opinión de permisos y no la solución al problema.

Comment: correcto, es que en la solución dada los comentarios hablan de problemas de permisos, pensé que estaba agregando un comentario a la respuesta de lois6b.